# Xcode 5 Slowing when opening "Connection inspector" on xib or storyboard file

Tags: storyboard, xcode5, xib, connection, outlet

I'm getting an issue with Xcode since a while.

When i'm in a storyboard or a xib file, and i want go to the connection inspector in the right panel, it's taking between 15 and 20 seconds to display all my outlets and actions of my ViewController. This is very slow and irritating...

[image: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/294154Capturedcran20140410141145.png]

I tried to clean all my derived data and archive to clean xcode content, but it doesn't resolve the problem

Anyone getting the same issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a large number of connections ?

Comment: Even for 2 connections it's taking at least 10 seconds

Comment: same probleme for me since a few days, no idea why it started.
right click on a view to show connections takes about 10 secondes after the great rainbow spinning ball of death !

Comment: What kind of computer do you have? is it a case of mavericks / xcode 5.1 are just too processor intensive?  Its not lightning quick on mine but opening a moderately sized storyboard isn't taking me 10 - 20 seconds

Comment: core i5 8Go Ram for me, my core2duo on my old macbookpro is faster jsute next to me. not sure it comes from computer performance.

Comment: I have and iMac 2,5GHz Core i5, 8Gb of RAM memory. Few weeks ago the time for opening the connection inspector was about 4 seconds maximum.

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin, even if it has 1000 connections, i can't take 20 seconds. It's just not possible.

Comment: so what is our the problem ?
so so long, so so frustrating!

Comment: the spinning rainbow ball is not visible when recording screen with QT. http://fr.tinypic.com/r/c2c28/8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution !

When right clicking, check your ressources monitor and see :
PrintTool 99%
cupsd 58%

I uninstall all print from my computer and the probleme is solved !

Geeeeeenius !! Don't really understand what XCode has to do with print tool !

I had like 40 printers in my system settings, I deleted them, but they kept coming back. this command solved the problème : [DISABLE CUPS](http://www.dgkapps.com/blog/osx-tips/osx-tips-turn-off-disable-cups-from-the-command-line/)

Comment: I also found that printtool CPU usage spiked. Repairing disk permissions helped, InstalledPrinters.plist and a few other printer related plists permissions were incorrectly set to rw-r-r when they should have been rw-rw-rw. Perhaps not having write access caused printtool to retry until it eventually timed out.